# How to traverse a nested dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have created a loop over a list of dictionaries. it works fine and looks like this:

```
  for dict in Employee:
    for k,v in dict.items():
        response = dynamodb.put_item(
            TableName=table_name,
            Item={
                'PK' : {'S' : f'ORG#{OrgId}'},
                'SK' : {'S' : f'EMP#{k}'},
                'entitytype': {'S' : f'{EntityType}'},
                'name': {'S' : f'{k}'},
                'email': {'S' : f'{v}'},
        }
    )
```

The list of dictionaries looks like this:

```
Employee = [{'Mark Mirnel':'mm@example.com'}, {'Kara Sawazsky': 'kz@example.com'}, {'Jorge Cressi': 'jc@example.com'}]
```

The next step is to expand the dictionary to this:

```
Employee = [{'223344':{'email':'mmy@example.com', 'name': 'Mark Mirnel'}}, {'445566':{'email':'cm@example.com', 'name': 'Clara Marx'}}]
```

I want to get the following values:

- id
- email
- name

The code looks like this:

```
Employee = [{'223344':{'email':'mmy@example.com', 'name': 'Mark   Myers'}}, {'445566':{'email':'cm@example.com', 'name': 'Clara    Marx'}}]
OrgId = '12345'
EntityType = 'employee'

for dict in Employee:
  for k,v in dict.items():
     for i,j in v.items():
        response = dynamodb.put_item(
            TableName=table_name,
            Item={
                'PK' : {'S' : f'ORG#{OrgId}'},
                'SK' : {'S' : f'EMP#{k}'},
                'entitytype': {'S' : f'{EntityType}'},
                'employee-id': {'S' : f'{k}'},
                'name': {'S' : f'{j}'},
                'email': {'S' : f'{j}'},
        }
    )
```

But I get twice the name and never the email. The result looks like this:

[image]

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

merci

A

Comment: Don't use dict to rename a variable because this is a built-in function that convert structures to a dict so you are overwriting this and cannot access this function anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it after some tinkering with the help of the community here. Thanks guys!!

```
for dict in Employees:
for k,v in dict.items():
    m = v['name']
    p = v['email']
    response = dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName=table_name,
        Item={
            'PK' : {'S' : f'ORG#{OrgId}'},
            'SK' : {'S' : f'EMP#{k}'},
            'entitytype': {'S' : f'{EntityType}'},
            'employee-id': {'S' : f'{k}'},
            'name': {'S' : f'{m}'},
            'email': {'S' : f'{p}'},
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
Employee = [{'223344':{'email':'mmy@example.com', 'name': 'Mark Mirnel'}}, {'445566':{'email':'cm@example.com', 'name': 'Clara Marx'}}]
for item in Employee:
    for key in item:
        print("Email for {} (Emp Id: {}): {}".format(item[key]["name"], key, item[key]["email"]))

Email for Mark Mirnel (Emp Id: 223344): mmy@example.com
Email for Clara Marx (Emp Id: 445566): cm@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
for dct in Employee:
    for key, d in dct.items():
        k, v = d['name'], d['email']
        response = dynamodb.put_item(
            ...
        )
```

Comment: it works well, but how to get the id (the key) as well (like '223344')

Comment: @aerioeus I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following changes to your code/schema:

- `Employee` -> `employees`, simple variable identifiers shouldn't
  start with an uppercase letter, and the plural-suffix `s` makes it
  more obvious that this is a collection of employee objects.
- Have `employees` be a dictionary mapping employee IDs to employees,
  rather than a list of dictionaries.

Code:

```
employees = {
    '223344': {
        'email': 'mmy@example.com',
        'name': 'Mark Mirnel'
    },

    '445566': {
        'email': 'cm@example.com',
        'name': 'Clara Marx'
    }
}

for employee_id, employee in employees.items():
    response = dynamodb.put_item(
        ...
        Item={
            ...
            'name': {'S': employee['name']},
            'email': {'S': employee['email']}
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can iterate over all items and put the dictionary inside the other, just alterate the "1234" for what you wish. An Id in your case.

To create a list use:

```
[{"1234":x} for x in Employee]
```

To get the values use:

```
l = [(k,v['email'],v['name']) for x in Employee for k,v in x.items()]
# [('223344', 'mmy@example.com', 'Mark Mirnel'), ('445566', 'cm@example.com', 'Clara Marx')]
```

So before your dinamodb.put you can access the value like:

```
for i in l:
    id, email, name = i
    
    print(id) # '445566'
    print(email) # 'cm@example.com'
    print(name) # 'Clara Marx'
```

Reference: [list compreensison](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: interesting solution. but where what kind of my solution shall i replace here?

Comment: merci for the update